# How to reference enum items generally in java

Tags: java, enums, reference

I have an enum class like this:

```
public enum EArea 
{
    DIRECTLANE,
    TURNLEFTLANE,
    INTERSECTION,
    SIDEWALK,
    FORBIDDEN;
}
```

I would like to build an AtomicRefrence from a value of this enum in another class:

```
public class CArea<T extends Enum<?>>
{
    private final AtomicReference<T> type;

    public CArea( ... ) //what should I put here?
    {
        type = new AtomicReference<T>( ... ); // and here?
    }
}
```

I want to do later:

```
CArea area1 = new CArea( EArea.SIDEWALK );
CArea area2 = new CArea( EArea.DIRECTLANE );
```

But I don't know how can I reference items of an enum in a method generally (here constructor).

Comment: Same as for any other generic situation - stuff like `public CArea(T t) { ... }` ought to be fine.

Comment: If you only pass EArea constants, you can just use `public CArea(EArea a)` and there is no need to use generics at all.

Comment: Enums are classes so like with any other class ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can pass the Enum value (an instance) to the constructor.

```
public class CArea<T extends Enum<T>>
{
    private final AtomicReference<T> type;

    public CArea(T enumVal)
    {
        type = new AtomicReference<>(enumVal);
    }
} 

CArea area1 = new CArea<>(EArea.SIDEWALK);
CArea area2 = new CArea<>(EArea.DIRECTLANE);
```

Note: With this the type parameter could be any enum.